# google maps transit directions html_instructions language

Tags: google-maps, directions

I am using Google Maps directions API to get directions in transit mode from the Google Maps API.

I can successfully read all the json objects and get the information i want but i have one problem.

The jsonarray that the api returns contains information about the next instruction to the user that is in GREEK language.

So when i try to parse the html_instructions i get the english part but i get strange letters for the greek part what can i do to fix this and diplay greek?

You can find an example of json by running the below api.

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Athens&destination=Kallithea&sensor=false&departure_time=1354320000&mode=transit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add parameter language=el in your request.